How can I clean up the useless python packages?
I tried to install the requirements for Grok on my server(I don’t have much disk space).
dm_haiku==0.0.12
jax[cuda12-pip]==0.4.25 -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_cuda_releases.html
numpy==1.26.4
sentencepiece==0.2.0

But I found they are so big that the disk quota exceeded.
Thus, I wanted to uninstall them.
I used pip uninstall -r requirements.txt to uninstall these packages and deleted all the cache files by using rm -rf ~/.cache/*.
However, the disk usage was still very high.
How can I clean up these packages?

pip uninstall will remove only the requirements you pass to it, not all other things they depend on.
List the full set of installed packages in your environment, like this:
pip freeze

Choose the subset you want to uninstall, and pass them to pip uninstall.
pip uninstall --yes -r requirements-to-remove.txt

This could possibly result in some packages being broken... use pip check to check for that (so you don't have to wait until a runtime error happens to discover that).
pip check

For example:
# run a Python 3.11 environment in Docker
docker run --rm -it python:3.11 bash

# install 'lightgbm' and 'pandas' (which both depend on 'numpy')
pip install lightgbm pandas

# that pulls in other dependencies, like 'numpy' and 'pytz'
pip freeze
# lightgbm==4.3.0
# numpy==1.26.4
# pandas==2.2.2
# ...

# if you just uninstall 'pandas', 'numpy' will still be in the environment
pip uninstall --yes pandas
pip freeze | grep numpy
# numpy==1.26.4

# if you then uninstall 'numpy' too, it'll break 'lightgbm'
pip uninstall --yes numpy
python -c "import lightgbm"
# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

# you could detect this with 'pip check'
pip check
# lightgbm 4.3.0 requires numpy, which is not installed.
# scipy 1.13.0 requires numpy, which is not installed.

# that could be fixed by reinstalling 'numpy'
pip install numpy

